# Amazon associates access with multiple logins?

Tags: amazon

Is it possible to set up multiple logins for access to an Amazon Associates account? (in a way similar to Google Analytics, for example)

If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Log in
- "Account Settings" in upper right
- "Manage account users and select your primary e-mail address"